# How to change my log4j2.xml RollingFile settings

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to modify my `log4j2.xml` file with a few modifications, but couldn't succeed. Here is my current version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/mylog.log"  filePattern="logs/mylog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log" append="false">
     <PatternLayout>
           <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
         </PatternLayout>
         <Policies>
          <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
          <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2"/>
      </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I don't want to save 2 files **per day**. I just need 2 backup files all the time, otherwise my logs will increase daily! I tried removing the date pattern from filename, but got an error: `filePattern="logs/mylog-%i.log"` didn't work.

Comment: You could try using the [delete action](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover) of the `RollingFile` appender to delete older files. With regard to `immediateFlush` it's a boolean parameter so just set it to `false` - what did you try?

Comment: ok thanks. Why producing a file and then delete?! So the file should have a date in the name? What is wrong with `filePattern="logs/mylog-%i.log"`?!

Comment: I suggested the delete action because it allows you to limit the total number of files and/or the age of the files, thus you could keep your time triggering policy while at the same time impose a limit on the age and/or number of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

As you can see, I had an empty `<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />` tag within my `<Policies>` list which was forcing the date check in the `filePattern` file name. Once I removed it, it started just working fine!

Comment: But if you want to have your log files roll-over each day, then you have to include the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.