# log4j2 RollingFile with filePattern and DefaultRolloverStrategy

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm currently using ***Log4J2 version 2.14.1*** (*as part of SpringBoot version 2.5.0*)

## What I Want to Do

I'm trying to add a ***RollingFile*** appender to my Log4J2 configuration which will:

- Roll-over on application startup.
- Roll-over when a maximum size has been reached (*10 MB in the below example*).
- Roll-over each day.
- Roll-over into indexed files with the date of their roll-over in the file-name and the parent folder-name.
- Only keep a finite number of archived/rolled-over files (*3 in the below example*).

## What I'd Like the Log Folder(s) to Look Like

There would only be a finite number of archived log files kept **across all days**.

```
-- logs
    |-- master-backend-log4j2.log
    |-- 2021-06
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-06-30-1.log.gz
    |-- 2021-07
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-07-01-1.log.gz
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-07-01-2.log.gz
```

## What the Log Folder(s) Look Like

There is a finite number of archived log files kept **per day**.
In my final configuration, the maximum number of files to keep would be much higher than 3, but this lower number makes the below examples easier :)

```
-- logs
    |-- master-backend-log4j2.log
    |-- 2021-06
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-06-29-1.log.gz
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-06-29-2.log.gz
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-06-29-3.log.gz
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-06-30-1.log.gz
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-06-30-2.log.gz
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-06-30-3.log.gz
    |-- 2021-07
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-07-01-1.log.gz
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-07-01-2.log.gz
         |-- master-backend-log4j2-2021-07-01-3.log.gz
```

## My Log4J2 Configuration

```
<RollingFile
    name="MasterRollingFile"
    fileName="./logs/master-backend-log4j2.log"
    filePattern="./logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/master-backend-log4j2-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz"
>
    <PatternLayout
        pattern="%d [%-5level] (%C) : %m%n%throwable"
    />
    <Policies>
        <!--
            Rollover on startup, per day and when
            the file reaches a maximum size.
        -->
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy
            minSize="1"
        />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
            size="10 MB"
        />
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
            interval="1"
            modulate="true"
        />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy
        max="3"
    />
</RollingFile>
```

## Duplicate Question with Inadequate Answer

I found this post with basically the same issue, but the person asking the question answered it herself by stating that the solution is to remove the time restrin:
[How to change my log4j2.xml RollingFile settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471663/how-to-change-my-log4j2-xml-rollingfile-settings)

Unfortunately this is not the solution that I'm looking for.